# How to catch AssertionError in a nested function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I'm writing a mocha clone, because mocha is lacking certain features that I need. But when I am using existing assertion libraries, I'm unable to catch errors that are returned by them. Here is the code that runs the tests.

```
Tester.Test = function(name, test_function) {
    this.name = name;
    this.run = function(callback) {
        try {
            test_function(callback);
        } catch (e) {
            callback(e);
        }
    };
};
```

I've already tried using `domain` to catch the error, but it's still not working:

```
var d = domain.create();
d.on("error", function(err) {
    cb(err);
});
d.run(function() {
    test.run(cb);
});
```

I still keep getting an `AssertionError` (expected false to be true). Any tips?

Comment: Mocha is a pretty well established testing framework. I'm kind of curious as to what feature is missing and why you don't put in a feature request or figure out how to add it yourself instead of rewriting the Mocha framework. It's going to take you a really long time to clone the Mocha testing framework.

Comment: Please show us the `test_function` that you are using whose errors you cannot catch. And where does that `AssertionError` come from?

Comment: It's ok, i got it. The framework i'm writing isn't specifically for unit-testing, but some other testing. I needed the ability to track progress within a test, and the ability to report results other than simply pass/fail. Mocha doesn't have much flexibility when it comes to this, given that it's a unit-testing framework.